# In Codename One, how do you read/write to an excel file and still have it compile?

Tags: excel, netbeans, codenameone

Are there any libraries that work with Codename One that would allow me to read/write to an excel file for the app I'm building? I've tried Apache POI, but I haven't gotten it to work with Codename One. I assume this because CN1 only supports certain libraries. If Apache POI does work with CN1, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Codename One has a CSV parser that allows you to read CSV files exported by typical spreadsheets but not the rather complex Excel file format. You can probably port POI to Codename One but that might require some effort.

Comment: I am now using the CSV parser but now I am getting an error when I try to input the file: 

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.csv"); 

gives me the error: 

cannot find symbol
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.csv");

Comment: That's a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804049/in-codename-one-why-can-i-not-get-fileinputstream-to-import-or-compile