# In Codename One, why can I not get FileInputStream to import or compile?

Tags: java, netbeans, codenameone

Here are my imports:

```
import com.codename1.ui.*;
import com.codename1.ui.util.*;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.*;
import com.codename1.ui.events.*;
import com.codename1.io.*;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.*;
import java.io.*;
```

I cannot get this code to compile:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("users.csv");
```

Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\Isaac\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CodenameOne_TESTING\src\com\fakecompany\testapp\MyApplication.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("users.csv");
  symbol:   class FileInputStream
  location: class MyApplication
```

I thought this might be a problem with the imports, and sure enough, when I specifically imported `java.io.FileImputStream` it gave me an additional error:

```
C:\Users\Isaac\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CodenameOne_TESTING\src\com\fakecompany\testapp\MyApplication.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import java.io.FileInputStream;
  symbol:   class FileInputStream
  location: package java.io
```

What is going on? Is there a different way I am supposed to import files in Codename One? Let me know if this is not enough of my code to find the error.

PS: I need to get an input stream implemented so I can parse the csv file:

```
    CSVParser parser = new CSVParser();
    String[][] data = parser.parse(in);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Codename One has omitted that class - and others, I suspect.

Judging by the documentation, I suspect you want to use the [`com.codename1.io.FileSystemStorage`](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html) class and its [`openInputStream`](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/io/FileSystemStorage.html#openInputStream(java.lang.String)) method.

You may well want to watch the [video on storing data to persistent storage](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---store-data-to-persistent-storage-storageexternalization.html) too.

Comment: How do I call the openInputStream method? (I'm a beginner with java and don't really have much knowledge with File IO)

Comment: @IsaacBeeman: If you're starting off with Java, I would start off with *vanilla* Java rather than something "like Java, but slightly different." Get to grips with the basics by writing console applications, and then you'll be in a much better position to handle more unusual environments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I am doing this for my Computer Science Internal Assessment and it is much too late for me to switch my program over to JavaFX (or something else). I figured this would be a challenge, and I was willing to struggle though it to get my app done. It has all been going well except when I have to figure out what CN1 does differently than the normal Java API. Also, thanks for the help, I got my app to read and write to the file.

Comment: Jon, I would argue that Codename One is simpler than plain Java in some regards since the API is smaller and a lot of common sense API's are builtin (e.g. CSVParsing). Current Java API's tend to be so over abstracted a newbie might find them daunting. I did upvote since your answer is indeed correct.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: While it may be simpler in some ways, there are orders of magnitude more examples, tutorials, books etc available for vanilla Java than for Codename One. Anyone doing a web search to find out how to do a particular task in Java is *overwhelmingly* more likely to find an answer which works in vanilla Java than in Codename One. For a new developer, that's a pretty unfriendly experience - whereas someone who already has experience in Java has a much better chance of adapting to the changes required for Codename One.

Comment: Vanilla Java sure, but most vanilla Java samples would apply to Codename One including most IO API's, Collections etc. Not to mention that you can search for Codename One and the question on Google to find out similar answers. If you are targeting mobile and want to do it in Java, Codename One is by an order of magnitude better documented than anything else out there with the exception of the Android SDK itself.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: I wasn't suggesting that the OP moved away from Codename One - just that they learned vanilla Java *first* before using it. In my experience, developers who *start* on a relatively unusual platform (compared to the vanilla one) will often get confused when they have an error - they won't know whether it's due to their inexperience in general, or a quirk of the platform. This isn't just for unusual platforms, either - I'd advise learning to write simple console apps before writing a GUI on *any* platform, just because there's so much less that can go wrong.

Comment: No problem, just a philosophical debate ;-) I generally really like teaching newbies in a "hands on" sort of approach. I think that once you get something running on the device its just so cool that it energizes the whole learning experience. That's why I always had a hard time teaching the old J2EE specs (1.1 days) you had to go thru so many hoops to reach something attractive/useful. I think plain old Java is problematic in that sense, the best you can do is Swing/JavaFX both effectively dead and dated.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: My experience of that is that the result is someone who can run into trouble really fast, and then have trouble diagnosing problems because they don't have a solid grounding. I've seen that hundreds of times over the years. While it may be more *exciting* to do something with fancy graphics etc right from the start, there's far more to take in that way than a plain console app, where you can see *all* the code in a tiny space, and try to understand the whole thing. No threads to worry about, etc...

Comment: I generally agree, but prefer a bit excitement, risky ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Jon's answer is correct but partial. The question is where is the CSV file actually stored...

If the file is in the src folder (part of your jar) use `Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/filename");`.

If you downloaded it, then its very likely you downloaded to storage and not necessarily file system (slightly different things in mobile). Both have rather detailed API's to open/write and the `Util` class has a nice download API. Keep in mind that you can't just "put" a file on the device like you can in a computer, the filesystem is quite different.

As a sidenote, Codename One has a builtin `CSVParser` class which could be useful for you.