# Store Data to file in CodeNameOne AND a Swing GUI java application

Tags: java, swing, serialization, codenameone

I've started using CodeNeme One to develop an app that displays a curriculum of data made up of modules, categories and topics in a hierarchical data structure (Modules contain categories which contain Topics).  My goal is to make this a general purpose framework within which the Data determines the app behaviour and content so organizations can customize the app by using a desktop GUI to edit data.

So I took a break from my mobile App Development to add a Swing GUI to generate the data model instead of hard-coded test data.

I used Java.io.ObjectInputStream/OutputStream to write my data structure conveniently to file and read it.  Then tried to use the file input and output code in my codenameOne project and got errors like in this StackOverflow question: [In Codename One, why can I not get FileInputStream to import or compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804049/in-codename-one-why-can-i-not-get-fileinputstream-to-import-or-compile) .

So, CodenameOne recommends use of their own APIs to read and write to storage.   **Is there a way I read and write the data files that my compiled CodenameOne App will be able to read, but in the Swing GUI Desktop application?**  How should I implement file (or hopefully object I/O) in the desktop GUI Swing app and then be able to package that data file with the app to compile it?

Answer (score 0):

We usually use a common format when interacting between JavaSE/EE and Codename One. So we use [XML or JSON](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_parsing_json_xml_csv) parsers/[generators](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/xml/XMLWriter.html) for which are available on both platforms and they allow us to be "future proof" for any type of technology.

We also have the ability to work with objects with our own custom externalization code, the [webservice wizard](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-remote-webservices-perform-operations-on-the-server.html) generates Java SE/EE compatible versions of these classes and you can use those within your Swing project.

FYI Codename One also supports desktop and JavaScript builds. We also have quite a lot of Swing applications and we are slowly migrating them to Codename One since Swing doesn't get updated anymore.

Comment: thanks for that @Shai.  I'll look for examples and documentation about XML/JSON Parsers/generators and the webservice wizard (is there an easy way to find that? a link you could provide perhaps?).   Can you provide a good example of a piece of code for reading or writing a complex object (with other objects in it) to a file that could be used in a desktop App to genreate the data file and in the mobile app to read and display the data?  if a good example is published somewhere, please provide a link.

Comment: You are right, my bad. I updated the post with some links. Notice that the XMLWriter is mostly a part of the javadoc. There are several strategies to generate valid JSON using the processing package but I don't use that myself since I think JSON is so simple you can just write it to a text file. Personally I usually go with XML. There are also other parsers in the cn1lib section http://codenameone.com/cn1libs.html  and a POJO mapper from Steve http://www.codenameone.com/blog/json-to-pojo-mapping which I'm not familiar enough with.